# Variable not defined in VBA script

Tags: vba, object, ms-access

I'm getting into the good habit of using `Option Explicit` at the top of all my MS Access VBA scripts. However, for this function it's giving me a `Variable not defined` error highlighting the line that begins with `Set objSysInfo =`

```
Public Function GetUser(Optional whatpart = "username")

    Dim returnthis As String
    If whatpart = "username" Then GetUser = Environ("USERNAME"): Exit Function
    Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
    Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objSysInfo.UserName)
    Select Case whatpart
        Case "fullname": returnthis = objUser.FullName
        Case "firstname", "givenname": returnthis = objUser.givenName
        Case "lastname": returnthis = objUser.LastName
        Case Else: returnthis = Environ("USERNAME")
    End Select
    GetUser = returnthis

End Function
```

Might I be missing a specific reference?

Comment: Where is objSysInfo defined?

Comment: @Jeremy it's *not* defined, that's the problem

Comment: Ah, good catch. I'm still a bit new to VBA, so how would I define this variable?

Comment: @Mat'sMug I know...I just wanted to be sure it wasn't defined at a module level that we couldn't see.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat Dim objSysInfo as Object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Option Explicit` **forces** you to *declare all variables*.

This means you **must** declare all variables you're using, otherwise your code won't compile - as you've noticed.

You declared local variable `returnthis` as a `String`, using the `Dim` keyword:

```
Dim returnthis As String
```

That's how you declare a *local* (*procedure scope*) variable.

You could declare variables at *module scope* using the `Private` keyword (`Dim` works as well, but better keep `Dim` for locals)

```
Option Explicit
Private foo As Object
```

How you *scope* variables depends on where you're using them - if a variable is only ever used in one single procedure, then it's better to scope it to that procedure and declare it as a local variable.

In this case you have `objSysInfo` and `objUser` that aren't declared anywhere.

```
Dim objSysInfo As Object
Dim objUser As Object
```

---

I know we're not on [Code Review](http://www.codereview.stackexchange.com), but while we're here there are other issues with your code:

- The return type of the function is implicitly `Variant`. Append `As String` to the end of the function's signature.
- The optional parameter `whatpart` is implicitly `Variant` as well, and implicitly passed `ByRef`, but you only need to *read* it, not *write and return to the caller* - so declare it `Optional ByVal whatpart As String = "username"`.
- Prefer the `Environ$` function over `Environ` - both do the same thing, but `Environ` returns a `Variant`, that you're implicitly converting to a `String` - best use `Environ$` and work with a string from the start.
- Instead of relying on magic, hard-coded strings, use an `Enum` value and `Select Case` over the possible legal values:

  ```
  Public Enum NamePart
      EnvironmentDefined
      FullName
      FirstName
      LastName
  End Enum
  ```

The full code could look like this:

```
Public Enum NamePart
    EnvironmentDefined
    FullName
    FirstName
    LastName
End Enum

Public Function GetUserName(Optional ByVal part As NamePart = EnvironmentDefined) As String

    Dim result As String
    Dim sysInfo As Object
    Dim userInfo As Object

    If Namepart = EnvironmentDefined Then 
        GetUser = Environ$("USERNAME")
        Exit Function
    End If

    Set sysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
    Set userInfo = GetObject("LDAP://" & sysInfo.UserName)
    Select Case part
        Case FullName
            result = userInfo.FullName
        Case FirstName
            result = userInfo.GivenName
        Case LastName
            result = userInfo.LastName
        Case Else
            result = Environ$("USERNAME")
    End Select

    GetUserName = result

End Function
```

Note, I didn't include a `GivenName` enum member, since it's redundant; calling code can do this:

```
Dim value As String
value = GetUserName(FirstName)
```

Comment: "to the end of the function's signature." ...the what? Where is a function's signature located? First line?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat the "signature" of a member is its access modifier, member type, name, parameter list and return type.

Comment: I edited my question to include the suggestions you've made. I'm not sure if I implemented your last bullet point correctly.

Comment: Type mismatch on `If Namepart = `

Comment: Well you changed it from a `String` to a `NamePart` enum type - you need to compare it to a `NamePart` value, not a `String` - that's the whole point, to use the enum to get rid of the magic strings.

Comment: I'm sorry! :/ I'm not experienced in VBA, so I'm not sure what you mean. How do I compare `NamePart` values?

Comment: A little addendum to a great answer: To have `Option Explicit` automatically in all new modules, set the [Require Variable Declaration](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/modules/options/index.html) option in the VBA Editor.